# Why would SearchResultItem.Paths be null?

Tags: solr, indexing, content-search

I am using Sitecore 8.1 with Solr 4.10 doing a general site search. I have a repeater on my search results page and I am binding the results to that repeater.  For some reason in my QA environment I am getting an error when I try to access searchHit.Document.Paths.  It is always coming back as null. This works fine in my local development environment.  Could it be a configuration problem?  Do I need to re-index?  Here is the code from my repeater. It fails on the IF statement because searchHit.Document.Paths is NULL.

```cs
    protected void rptResults_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
            var searchHit = (SearchHit<GeneralSearchResultItem>) e.Item.DataItem;
            var hypItem = (HyperLink) e.Item.FindControl("hypItem");
            var spnIcon = (HtmlGenericControl) e.Item.FindControl("spnIcon");
            var litTitle = (Literal) e.Item.FindControl("litTitle");
            var litDescription = (Literal) e.Item.FindControl("litDescription");

            var mediaLibraryRootItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/media library");

            if (searchHit.Document.Paths.Contains(mediaLibraryRootItem.ID)) {
                hypItem.NavigateUrl = searchHit.Document.ItemUrl;
                litTitle.Text = searchHit.Document.MediaTitle;
                litDescription.Text = TruncateString(searchHit.Document.MediaDescription, 200);
            }
            else {
                hypItem.NavigateUrl = searchHit.Document.ItemUrl;
                litTitle.Text = searchHit.Document.Title;
                litDescription.Text = TruncateString(searchHit.Document.Description, 200);
            }


            var iconClass = searchHit.Document.IconClass;
            if (iconClass != "") {
                spnIcon.Attributes["class"] = "icon " + iconClass;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you check in your config files if you the stored attribute is true defintion of field _path <field name="_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

Comment: You need to re-index -  yes.

Comment: Yes I have the _path field set up as you described

Comment: can you check also in schema.xml file if path's stored attribute is true?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber - yes that is where I looked.  I looked in the schema.xml file.  Is is showing there as <field name="_path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />.  This is for the sitecore_web_index core. Is there somewhere else besides that where I should look also?

Comment: Just a quick check - your item that is being indexed, do you see that in the web database? Sometimes, if an item has been removed, and the reindexing somehow fails (there can be many reasons to why this may happen), you can still fetch some details on it, but not the entire item details. I'd be sure to set the attribute on the path for both my master and web indexes as well.

Comment: Have you tried using Luke (https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/). This will let you connect directly to the index Solr uses. Then you can see if the path is not being indexed properly.

Answer (score 2):

I rebuilt the index completely and that seems to have fixed the problem.  I am no longer getting the NULL error.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you say it works on your machine but not on the QA box it does look like environment related(either configurations are not set properly or the value is not being indexed properly. Before you go out comparing configuration files have you tried using an index browser like [Luke](https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/)? with this tool you can easily check what the values are being set on the index for whatever fields you need. If they are properly indexed you know it's not an indexing issue and most likely a misconfiguration between environments. If that's the case I would suggest comparing configs looking for the misconfiguration